# Parse push notification send not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-manifest, send

I cannot send pushnotification from my application via Parse. I checked every settings:

- Manifest has been set correctly (permissions, package names)
- Parse has been initialized (with right keys), and localdatastore enabled
- All device use the same pushnotification channel, and subscribed to it
- On the Parse admin page, "Client push enabled" checked

After all of this, i want to send a pushnotification, but i cannot do this. I started to debug this issue.

First of all, i checked that the push notification had been sent or not.

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel(channel);
push.setMessage(message);
push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.d("SEND PUSH", (e == null) ? "SUCCESSFULL": "FAILED");                        
        }
    });
```

But this method returns with "SUCCESSFULL". So it has to be good. But on the Parse admin page and on the devices it is not showing.

I was curious, that i can receive push notifications, so i sent a pushnotification to my channel, from the parse admin page. And that worked.

So i think, the problem is in the sending method or in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="conversation.laszlomagyar.hu" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<!-- parse permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="conversation.laszlomagyar.hu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="conversation.laszlomagyar.hu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ApplicationObject">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.StarterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ui.Activity"
        android:label="@string/rooms"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".ui.Activitytwo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <activity android:name=".ui.Activitythree"
        android:label="@string/create_room"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <!-- parse stuffs -->

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="conversation.laszlomagyar.hu" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Do you subscribe the channel also with the device? ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(channel);

Comment: yes, i subscribed to it

Comment: @LászlóMagyar  u got solution i also subscribe but failed to send to specific user

Comment: @LászlóMagyar  try this line   push.setQuery(ParseInstallation.getQuery().whereEqualTo("Channels","channel")); instead of this push.setChannel(channel);

Comment: I tried but this is not working too.